# Clip feature according to its areas

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, area, sorting

I have a layer that has several overlapping areas (coming from CAD). So usually I do a "SORT" (tool), so I can view all the features. However, I wonder clip a shape according to their areas, it's means, to clip the lower area, to the largest area. Anyone know how?

Comment: The sentence that starts with "However" is unclear.  Perhaps a word or phrase is missing?  Please **edit** the question.